# How to force CSS grid column to take as much space as possible within parent container?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following layout:

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(100%) auto;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.a {
  background-color: #feb5f5;
}

.b {
  background-color: #76daff;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column; background-color: #ddff33">
  <div style="max-width: 1500px; background-color: #ccaa44; display:flex; align-items: first baseline; flex-direction: column;">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="grid-item a">Constant</div>
      <div class="grid-item b">Variable size content that should take as much space as possible</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should behave according to following rules. I'm coming with WPF background but struggle to fully implement them in HTML/CSS:

1. Page content has max width of 1500px and is horizontally centered. If viewport is smaller than 1500px, than content should shrink (in other words be responsive with upper limit).
2. That centered content itself is a grid of two columns:

   1. Left column should take minimal horizontal space (`Auto` column size in `WPF`).
   2. Right column should take all space available (`*` column size in `WPF`):

      1. Up to hitting 1500px limit if viewport is large enough.
      2. Up to taking all viewport space left if it is smaller than 1500px.

This wouldn't be a problem without "centered 1500px" rule (`1fr` or `auto` or `max-content` column sizes work for me then), but as you can see in above code snipped, when inside parent container grid doesn't take all 1500px available.

StackOverflow snipped width is 800px, which means that there should be no yellow space at all here.

The problem with such behaviour is that (in my app) content of the right column can be reloaded by js code, which leads to it having zero width for a fraction of second. With current layout it means that left column "jumps" towards the center and back for a fraction of second which looks bad.

I was trying to achieve solution in two ways:

1. Try different grid column sizes to make it take all space it can (seems to not work).
2. Introduce additional container within 1500px container that will take all space available and center child grid to the left. I feel that this should be possible, but can't wrap my head around how exactly.
3. Maybe I should center and limit to 1500px child grid using something else than flex container in my snippet?

If 2 would work correctly, layout with viewport >1500px would look like this:
[image]

I also have Bootstrap 4 available but was hoping that I can use CSS grid exclusively for layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply center using `margin:auto`

```css
[container] {
/*     display: flex; */
/*     align-items: center; */
/*     flex-direction: column; */
    background-color: #ddff33
}

[widthconstraint] {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: #ccaa44;
/*     display: flex; */
/*     align-items: first baseline; */
/*     flex-direction: column; */
}

.table {
    display: grid;
    /*   grid-template-columns: fit-content(100%) auto; */
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.grid-item {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.a {
    background-color: #feb5f5;
}

.b {
    background-color: #76daff;
}
```

```html
<div container>
  <div widthconstraint>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="grid-item a">Constant</div>
      <div class="grid-item b">Variable size content that should take as much space as possible</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The issue with your code is that flex items have `flex-shrink:1;flex-grow:0;` by default, so they won't grow to fill the parent and they will shrink to fit their content, The fix is pretty obvious if you want to center using flexbox.

```css
[container] {
    display: flex;
    /*     align-items: center; */
    /*     flex-direction: column; */
    justify-content: center;
    /* Align horizontally */
    background-color: #ddff33
}

[widthconstraint] {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    max-width: 1500px;
    background-color: #ccaa44;
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: first baseline; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
}

.table {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    display: grid;
    /*       grid-template-columns: fit-content(100%) auto; */
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.grid-item {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.a {
    background-color: #feb5f5;
}

.b {
    background-color: #76daff;
}
```

```html
<div container>
  <div widthconstraint>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="grid-item a">Constant</div>
      <div class="grid-item b">Variable size content that should take as much space as possible</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note: The code is self explanatory, However if you have any questions please do ask.** 
*I took the liberty to clean up the code a bit*

Comment: Thanks!
I used code from your first solution (like the simplicity) and it worked flawlessly, only had to tweak `auto -> fit-content(any%)` to completely remove "jumping" when changing content.
I recall trying `margin: auto` but probably made something wrong and couldn't make it work, so thanks for your simple and elegant solution.

And thanks for taking your time to explain how to make work both methods (flex and non-flex)!

Comment: @ArXen42 I changed `fit-content(100%) auto` to `auto 1fr` because the [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content) on `fit-content()` is not as wide. Did it not work for you ?

Comment: It _almost_ worked:)

In my app right panel contains some somewhat complex dynamic content (embedded control that is removed and loaded again on user action) and content of left column itself is slightly responsive (can shrink when there is not enough space).
With `auto 1fr` whole grid shrinked just a little (much less than before though) for a fraction of second during right column content reload. When I changed to `fit-content(100%) 1fr` it stopped shrinking completely.

I guess that was caused by my content somewhere.